# how to create an issue in jira via rest api?

Tags: rest, jira

Is it possible to create an issue in jira using REST api? I didn't find this in the documentation (no POST for issues), but I suspect it's possible.

A wget or curl example would be nice.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

POST to this URL

```
https://<JIRA_HOST>/rest/api/2/issue/
```

This data:

```
{
"fields": {
   "project":
   { 
      "key": "<PROJECT_KEY>"
   },
   "summary": "REST EXAMPLE",
   "description": "Creating an issue via REST API",
   "issuetype": {
      "name": "Bug"
   }
  }
}
```

In received answer will be ID and key of your ISSUE:

```
{"id":"83336","key":"PROJECT_KEY-4","self":"https://<JIRA_HOST>/rest/api/2/issue/83336"}
```

Don't forget about authorization. I used HTTP-Basic one.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the authorization you mentioned? Is there any need to pass the username & password of the project owner? Or would REST accept the POST with just the URL, Header (json) and Data?

Comment: I'm actually getting an error saying "400 Bad Request...field: summary cannot be set"

Comment: @Tru yes. HTTP-Basic autorization is [type of autorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). AFAIK there is another possible options for autorization. From [manual](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/): `The prefered authentication methods are HTTP Basic (when using SSL) and OAuth, which are both documented in the JIRA REST API Tutorials. Other supported methods include: HTTP Cookies, Trusted Applications, and os_username/os_password query parameters.`

Comment: Could you write an example of the exact curl call to use with the HTTP Basic authorization?

Comment: curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta

Comment: I am Getting this error :: M I missing something?            

{ errorMessages: [],
  errors: 
   { summary: 'Field \'summary\' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.',
     description: 'Field \'description\' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.' } }

Comment: @Smita, this answer is 5 years old. Something might change.

Comment: @msangel Unfortunately Atlassian hasn't changed much, including their authorization schema. Hope for the best in the next 5 years.

Comment: @Smita not sure if it helps, but because the screens you are assigning to when creating a ticket may or may not have the fields listed, it will respond as such. Verify the screen you are posting to and changing have the fields listed.

Comment: How to attach an image in project?

Answer (score 9):

The REST API in JIRA 5.0 contains methods for creating tasks and subtasks.

(At time of writing, 5.0 is not yet released, although you can access 5.0-m4 from the [EAP](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/EAPDownloads.jspa) page. The doco for create-issue in 5.0-m4 is [here](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/5.0-m4/#id4351931)).

Answer (score 7):

As of the latest released version (4.3.3) it is not possible to do using the [REST API](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/4.3.3/). You can create issues remotely using the JIRA SOAP API.

See [this page](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+SOAP+Client) for an example Java client.

Comment: For some reason (lack of standard compliance), the soap api implies a dependency on axis, specifically. I can't introduce this in my application. I'm quite sure there is a way (possibly: writing a jira plugin, which I'll do if I don't have any better solution).

Answer (score 4):

This is C# code:

```c#
string postUrl = "https://netstarter.jira.com/rest/api/latest/issue";

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("JIRAMMS:JIRAMMS"));

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = @"{""fields"":{""project"":{""key"": ""JAPI""},""summary"": ""REST EXAMPLE"",""description"": ""Creating an issue via REST API 2"",""issuetype"": {""name"": ""Bug""}}}";

    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question more direct, i.e. using cURL.

To use cURL to access JIRA REST API in creating a case, use

```
curl -D- -u <username>:<password> -X POST --data-binary "@<filename>"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://<jira-host>/rest/api/2/issue/
```

And save this in your < Filename> (please edit the field per your Jira case) and save in the folder you call the cURL command above.

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       { 
           "key": "<PROJECT_KEY>"
       },
       "summary": "REST EXAMPLE",
       "description": "Creating an issue via REST API",
       "issuetype": {
           "name": "Bug"
       }
   }
}
```

This should works. (note sometimes if it errors, possibly your content in the Filename is incorrect).

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use REST + JSON to create issues.

To check which json fields you can set to create the issue use: 
https://jira.host.com/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta

For more information please see the JIRA rest documentation:
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/6.2.4/

Comment: The ability to use the REST API to do more than read data was part of JIRA 5.x for anyone who wants to know. The REST API hasn't changed that much since then.

Answer (score 1):

To send the issue data with REST API we need to construct a valid JSON string comprising of issue details.

A basic example of JSON string:

```
 {“fields” : { “project” : { “key” : “@KEY@” } , “issuetype” : { “name” : “@IssueType@” } } }
```

Now, establish connection to JIRA and check for the user authentication.
Once authentication is established, we POST the REST API + JSON string via XMLHTTP method.
Process back the response and intimate user about the success or failure of the response.

So here JiraService being an XMLHTTP object, something like this will add an issue, where EncodeBase64 is a function which returns encrypted string.

```
Public Function addJIRAIssue() as String
With JiraService
    .Open "POST", <YOUR_JIRA_URL> & "/rest/api/2/issue/", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncodeBase64
    .send YOUR_JSON_STRING

    If .Status <> 401 Then
        addJIRAIssue = .responseText
    Else
        addJIRAIssue = "Error: Invalid Credentials!"
    End If

End With

Set JiraService = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can check out a [complete VBA example here](http://ashuvba.blogspot.in/2014/08/excel-vba-json-rest-with-jira-json-is.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I accepted an answer 2 years ago and I'll stick with it. I was interested in the API doc, not really in a vb example (i.e. the only thing I was interested in was what would be in YOUR_JSON_STRING here).

Comment: sure, no issues. just wanted to post the answer so that when some one with VBA and JIRA needs come to this link, they might find this useful . I agree with you and the accepted answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

In order to **create an issue**, set a **time estimate** and **assign** it to yourself, use this:

1. Generate an [Atlassian token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html)
2. Generate & save a base64-encoded auth token:

   `export b64token="$(echo "<your_email>:<generated_token>" | openssl base64)"`
3. Make a POST request:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://<your_jira_host>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/ \
     -H 'Accept: */*' \
     -H 'Authorization: Basic $b64token \
     -d '{
       "fields":{
         "project":{
           "key":"<your_project_key (*)>"
         },
         "issuetype":{
           "name":"Task"
         },
         "timetracking":{
           "remainingEstimate":"24h"
        },
         "assignee":{
           "name":"<your_name (**)>"
       },
       "summary":"Endpoint Development"
     }
   }'
```

---

*Remarks:*

(*) Usually a short, capitalized version of the project description such as: ...atlassian.net/projects/**UP**/.

(**) if you don't know your JIRA name, cURL GET with the same Authorization as above to `https://<your_jira_host>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=<any_project_name>` and look for `issues.fields.assignee.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbling on this and am having issues creating an issue via the REST API.

```
issue_dict = {
    'project': {'key': "<Key>"},
    'summary': 'New issue from jira-python',
    'description': 'Look into this one',
    'issuetype': {'name': 'Test'},
}
new_issue = jira.create_issue(issue_dict)
```

new_issue returns an already existing issue and doesn't create one.