# Jira submission from a web page

Tags: html, http, jira

I am trying to use the Jira REST API to submit issues.
This answer gives a POST method to submit issues
[how to create an issue in jira via rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884960/how-to-create-an-issue-in-jira-via-rest-api)
Is there a way to integrate POST with html so you could submit things from a webpage?
If this is not possible, is there another way to create jira issues from a webpage?

I initially tried using the issue collector but it does not offer enough flexibility. 
We are trying to have three required fields that combine to form the description, much like how the first example feedback from in the issue collector has a rating and then "what did you like" "what did you not like" boxes.

Sorry this question was initially rather unclear.

Thank you!

Comment: i'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JIRA API is primarily intended for use from scripts, not from web pages. There is no way to securely allow a web page to access the JIRA API directly.

If you want to allow users to create JIRA issues from a web page, use a [JIRA issue collector](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/using-the-issue-collector-288657654.html).

Comment: (The documentation I linked to is down right now; if you're in a hurry, you may want to check [the Google cache of that page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:IecrQNm47x8J:https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/using-the-issue-collector-288657654.html).)

Comment: The JIRA issue collector doesn't allow enough flexibility. We wanted to have three required fields and then combine them all in the description which is impossible to do in the issue collector.